# 404 for Angular app located in .NET wwwroot folder after refresh

Tags: .net, angular, iis

I just create simple basic .NET Core 6 and Angular 16 applications.

I run

```
ng build --base-href=/ --output-path=D:\\myApp
```

and then I move all this build files to wwwroot folder in angular application.

my Program.cs class :

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(m => m.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
```

All is hosted on IIS, there is WebApplication with all dll's, web.config <for .NET app> files and wwwroot folder , in this wwwroot folder I also got web.config for angular application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="AngularRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: If you are getting a 404 even with the StaticFiles enabled, can you check if you can access a single index.html file with some dummy content?

Comment: Your `<rule name="AngularRule" ` simply breaks every request because it's executed by IIS long before ASP.NET Core's static-file handler sees the request, and IIS _doesn't know_ that ASP.NET Core is handling the serving of static files under `$websiteRoot\wwwroot` but IIS thinks static files are directly under `$websiteRoot`.

Comment: @V.S Yes, with just index.html all works fine

Comment: @Dai okey but API works 100% fine.. just angular has 404 error after refresh..

Comment: @ruddnisrus AFTER REFRESH is veryimportant bit of info. I have updated my answer for thiat.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html, does the    match the folder in IIS? Typically  \inetpub\wwwroot\someapp   but in your case  d:\myapp

If you have a pluralsight subscribtion, there are videos by Shawn Wildermuth specifically on using .net and angular together.

Also, I am used to seeing Cors setup in two parts.

Setting up in services:

> ```
>  services.AddCors(options =>
>  {
>   options.AddPolicy("MyAllowedOrigins",
>   policy =>
>   {
>   policy
>   .AllowAnyOrigin()
>   .AllowAnyHeader()
>   .AllowAnyMethod();
>    });
> });
> ```

Calling in app:
app.UseCors("MyAllowedOrigins");

UPDATE #1

The OP mentioned 404 on refresh. There are many ways to setup IIS, Angular, etc. This sounds like a redirect issue.

Using the hash in the Angular route will should address this issue.

RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
{
useHash: true
}

If this fixes it, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: from d:\myapp I just take staff and copy it to windows server environment, CORS are okey in that case, I also use it <forgot to add here> but it's not that case, I just don't know how to configure this two web.configs , I also cannot find any useful staff related to IIS configuration on Shawn content;/

Comment: The IIS setup is very straightforward. You do not need / should create any additional web.config files. Just copy the files from the publish folder to appropriate folder on the IIS several. Create an appPool that is No Managed Services. Create an App that uses the newly created appPool. If the IIS server can host a default .net6 web app published straight from the template, it will have no issues hosting an angular app. The angular app requires less from the IIS Server than .net 6.

Answer (score 0):

When building your Angular application, you specified --base-href=/. This means that your Angular application expects to be served from the root of your domain. Therefore, you don't need to rewrite URLs in your web.config. Instead, you can simply serve the Angular files directly from the wwwroot folder.

You don't need a separate web.config file for your Angular application in the wwwroot folder. The one you have in the root of your ASP.NET Core application should suffice.

Here's what you can do:

Remove the rewrite rule from the web.config in the wwwroot folder.

Make sure your Angular application is built with the correct base href. If your Angular application will be served from a subdirectory, you should specify that subdirectory as the base href during the build process.